# What Scala annotations modify the compiler's messages?

Tags: scala, annotations, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I know about two:

- `@deprecated("use blabla instead")` is used to add an explanation to the warning output by the compiler when the annotated definition is used in client code.
- `@implicitNotFound(msg = "more meaningful explanation")` is used to output an additional error message whenever an implicit of the type of the annotated definition cannot be found. Looking at `CanBuildFrom`, msg can contain placeholders of the type `${A}` if `A` is the name of a type parameter of the annotated type, which is filled in by the compiler with the actual expected type, e.g.:

  ```
  @implicitNotFound(msg = "Cannot construct a collection of type ${To} with elements of type ${Elem} based on a collection of type ${To}.")
  trait CanBuildFrom[-From, -Elem, +To] { ... }
  ```

Are there any other such annotations?

Comment: @Daniel I'll second that motion...

Comment: Hmm, a great question, and I upvoted it, but it's pretty unlikely that there will actually be an acceptable answer, barring someone on the Scala team chiming int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is `@migration`, which is used with `-Xmigration` to indicate semantic changes in methods from one version to another, in helping port code between versions.

```
@migration(2, 8, "As of 2.8, keys returns Iterable[A] rather than Iterator[A].")
```

Answer (score 6):

There is @tailrec, which makes the compiler output an error if tail call optimization cannot be applied to the annotated method.

Answer (score 3):

As of Scala 2.9, there's also `@deprecatedName`: “An annotation that designates the name of the parameter to which it is applied as deprecated. Using that name in a named argument generates a deprecation warning.”